# Probability distribution function F(X)

Tags: probability

Let $X$ be a random variable with probability distribution function $F(x)$, expected value $E(x)=\mu$ and variance $Var(X)=\sigma^2$. Now let $Y=2X$ and $Z=10-X$. Find the probability distribution functions $F_z(Z)$ and $F_y(Y)$.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**: 
$$
F_Y(y)=P(Y\leq y)=P(2X\leq y)
$$
and
$$
F_Z(z)=P(Z\leq z)=P(10-X\leq z).
$$
With the given information, the best we can do is find $F_Z$ and $F_Y$ in terms of $F_X$, and this does not really require us to know what the mean or variance is (or even to know if they exist).

Comment: Got it :) Is the final answer: F_z(Z)=1-F(10-z) and F_y(Y)=F(y/2) ?

Comment: @Natalie: The second one is correct. In the derivation of the first I think you have used that $P(X\geq x)=1-P(X\leq x)$ - something which only holds if you know that $P(X=x)=0$ (in particular if you know that $X$ has a pdf). In general you only know that $P(X\geq x)=1-P(X<x)$ and $P(X< x)=P(X\leq x)-P(X=x)$.